# Mongoose - Cannot modify field value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am building a simple shop backend for practice purposes. I have three schemas `Product`, `Customer` and `Order`.

What I am trying to achieve is to subtract the ordered quantity from the stock quantity for each product inside an order, when the order is created. Clearly I am doing something wrong cause my `productsToUpdateInDbArray` contains the correct products (checked it with console log) but I can't find a way to make it work.

`stockQty` field inside Products collection is not updating.

My controller code is:

```
'use strict'

// require validator for string validation
const validator = require('validator');
// import Order, Customer, Product Models
const Order = require("../models/order.model");
const Customer = require("../models/customer.model");
const Product = require("../models/product.model");

// DEFINE CONTROLLER FUNCTIONS

// listAllOrders function - To list all orders
exports.listAllOrders = (req, res) => {
    Order.find({}, (err, orders) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(`Internal server error: ${error}`);
        }

        if (orders && orders.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).send(`No orders found!`);
        }

        return res.status(200).json(orders);
    });
};

// createNewOrder function - To create new order
exports.createNewOrder = (req, res) => {
    const customerId = req.body?.customerId;
    const productsArray = req.body?.products;

    let productsToUpdateInDbArray = [];

    if (!validator.isMongoId(customerId)) {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid customer Id');
    }

    Customer.findById(customerId, async (err, customer) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(`Internal server error: ${error}`);
        }

        if (!customer) {
            return res.status(404).send(`No customers found!`);
        }

        if (!productsArray || productsArray.length === 0) {
            return res.status(400).send(`No products found in the order!`);
        }

        for (let product of productsArray) {
            if (!validator.isMongoId(product?.productId)) {
                return res.status(400).send('Invalid product Id');
            }

            if (!product?.quantity || product?.quantity < 1) {
                return res.status(400).send('Invalid product quantity');
            }

            let productFound = await Product.findById(product?.productId).exec();
            
            if (!productFound) {
                return res.status(404).send('Product not found!');
            }

            if (productFound.stockQty < product.quantity) {
                return res.status(400).send('Not enough product quantity in stock')
            }

            productFound.stockQty -= product.quantity;
            productsToUpdateInDbArray.push(productFound);
        }

        console.log(productsToUpdateInDbArray)

        const newOrder = new Order(req.body);
        newOrder.save((err, order) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(`Internal server error: ${error}`);
            }

            for (let item of productsToUpdateInDbArray) {
                const filter = { _id: item._id };
                const update = { stockQty: item.stockQty };

                Product.findOneAndUpdate( filter, update )
            }
            return res.status(201).json(order);
        });
    });
};
```

And my models are:

```
'use strict';

// Import mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Declare schema and assign Schema class
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema Instance and add schema propertise
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    stockQty: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

// create and export model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Products", ProductSchema);
```

```
'use strict';

// Import mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Declare schema and assign Schema class
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema Instance and add schema propertise
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    products: [
        {
            productId: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: true,
                ref: "Products"
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            }
        }
      ],
    customerId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "Customers"
    }
});

// create and export model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Orders", OrderSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` will only execute the query when a `callback` is passed. So in your case you can either add an `await` or `callback`.

```js
await Product.findOneAndUpdate( filter, update );
```

or

```js
Product.findOneAndUpdate( filter, update, callback );
```

Comment: I tried adding "await" and I get an error indicating that await is only valid in async function.

Comment: I added async on "newOrder.save" and it worked. Thanks a lot!